# Cannot deserialize element in SOAP response from Ofbiz

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl, ofbiz

I am trying to call a SOAP service deployed on ofbiz instance running on my local machine itself using node:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'https://localhost/webtools/control/SOAPService/testSoapSimple?wsdl';
var args = {'login.username':'flexadmin', 'login.password':'ofbiz'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(client.describe());
    client.testSoapSimple.testSoapSimplePort.testSoapSimple(args,function(err, result, raw, soapHeader){
        console.log(result);
        console.log(raw);
    });
});
```

The console output looks like:

```
{ testSoapSimple: { testSoapSimplePort: { testSoapSimple: [Object] } } }
{ 'map-Map': { 'map-Entry': [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><testSoapSimpleResponse xmlns="http://ofbiz.apache.org/service/"><map-Map>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="responseMessage"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="error"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="errorMessage"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="Cannot deserialize element named login.username"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
    </map-Map></testSoapSimpleResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

It returns the value as **Cannot deserialize element named login.username**.
I checked the logs and it says:

```
2015-08-28 22:30:28,218 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-443-exec-29) [   SOAPEventHandler.java:233:ERROR] 
---- exception report ----------------------------------------------------------
Exception: org.ofbiz.entity.serialize.SerializeException
Message: Cannot deserialize element named login.username
---- stack trace ---------------------------------------------------------------
org.ofbiz.entity.serialize.SerializeException: Cannot deserialize element named login.username
org.ofbiz.entity.serialize.XmlSerializer.deserializeCustom(XmlSerializer.java:478)
org.ofbiz.entity.serialize.XmlSerializer.deserializeSingle(XmlSerializer.java:460)
org.ofbiz.entity.serialize.XmlSerializer.deserialize(XmlSerializer.java:128)
org.ofbiz.service.engine.SoapSerializer.deserialize(SoapSerializer.java:45)
org.ofbiz.webapp.event.SOAPEventHandler.invoke(SOAPEventHandler.java:180)
org.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.runEvent(RequestHandler.java:662)
org.ofbiz.webapp.control.RequestHandler.doRequest(RequestHandler.java:406)
org.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlServlet.doGet(ControlServlet.java:224)
org.ofbiz.webapp.control.ControlServlet.doPost(ControlServlet.java:87)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.ofbiz.webapp.control.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:344)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can anybody explain what am I doing wrong? Or if there is something wrong with the WSDL that has been provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the SOAP format which I was trying to send was not in the appropriate format provided by the service provider.
"login.username" was being considered as an element here where as it should be the value of an attribute. For example in this case it might be something like :

```
<map-Map>
        <map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <login.username>123456</login.username>
            </map-Key>
        </map-Entry>
<map-Map>
```

which is not compliant to what the service provider supports. It should be something like :

```
<map-Map>
<map-Entry>
            <map-Key>
                <std-String value="login.username"></std-String>
            </map-Key>
            <map-Value>
                <std-String value="123456"></std-String>
            </map-Value>
        </map-Entry>
<map-Map>
```